# Laravel Datatables: Unable to access changed primary key column

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I was working in `laravel yajra datatables`, everything works fine but if I use my default primary key column as `id` but for security purpose, I just changed the `id` column to `team_id` and when yajra load the records it's still searching for column `id`:

**Datatable Code:**

```
protected function getColumns()
{
return [
    Column::make('team_id'),
    Column::make('name')->addClass('text-left'),
    Column::make('logo')->addClass('text-center')->orderable(false),
    Column::make('captain')->addClass('text-right'),
    Column::make('wicketKeeper')->addClass('text-right')->title('Wicket Keeper'),
    Column::make('substitute')->addClass('text-right'),
    Column::make('city_id')->addClass('text-right')->title('City'),
    Column::make('created_at'),
    Column::computed('action')
        ->exportable(false)
        ->printable(false)
        ->width(150)
        ->addClass('text-center'),
];
}
```

As you can see my datatable `getColumns` function has `team_id` column, even I changed the primary key column in my `Team` model also

**Team Model**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'team_id';
```

but still getting same error: `Unknown column teams.id in where clause`

casn anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Have you changed the $fillable? 
or this? protected $primaryKey = 'team_id';

Also, can you try this out?

    `Column::make('team_id', function($query) {
       return $query->('team_id');
    }),`

Comment: yes i changed in fillable also and `return $query->('team_id')` gives me error

Answer (score 0):

For Example In Laravel's Controller:

```
public function getMultiFilterSelect()
{
    return view('datatables.eloquent.multi-filter-select');
}
public function getMultiFilterSelectData()
{
    $users = User::select(['team_id', 'name', 'email', 'logo', 'captain', 'wicketKeeper', 'substitute', 'city_id']);
    return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
}
```

In Javascript Code:

```
$('#users-table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: 'https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/multi-filter-select-data',
    columns: [
        {data: 'team_id', name: 'team_id'},
        {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
        {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
        {data: 'logo', name: 'logo'},
        {data: 'captain', name: 'captain'},
        {data: 'wicketKeeper', name: 'wicketKeeper'},
        {data: 'substitute', name: 'substitute'},
        {data: 'city_id', name: 'city_id'}
    ],
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
            .on('change', function () {
                column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

If you are still getting some issue regarding the datatables,you easily follow the document https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/multi-filter-select

Comment: but I am using datatable as service (datatable class)

Comment: have you follow this document ??
https://datatables.yajrabox.com/service

Comment: yea, i followed, but my question was I just changed the default primary key `id` to `team_id`